# iReport to DB2 connection ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001

Tags: db2, ireport

I am using Jasper iReport.
When I try to connect to IBM DB2 I get an error: "Permission denied: ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001"

I am using the same driver to connect as Razor which I also use and there it works ok (same settings, username, password, etc).

This problem started to occur lately.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Did you happen to include DB2 jar file in ireport classpath??
I mean you might have missed it..!!

Comment: i have included it. Ihave the same settings as before. Just now it is not workin. Could it be a problem with java (32 bit vs 64bit)?

Comment: Does anybody has an answer. I really need this

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14562421 might help..!!

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that any firewalls and/or proxy servers in between have been configured to let your requests through. We had a similar error & it turned out to be that the firewall between our appserver & db2 did not have the required port open.